# How to change the Tab Bar color in Xamarin iOS?

Tags: c#, ios, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, updates

After the visual studio update the color of the selected icon of the tab bar is back to the default one does anyone know why?

This was the line of code that I had used before the update to change the color

> UITabBar.Appearance.SelectedImageTintColor = UIColor.Black;

the visual studio version is 8.3.11

Comment: I have submitted it as an issue [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/9070) , you can follow it up there . By the way , I found a workaround in Xamarin.Forms . You can have a look at it when have time .

Answer (score 1):

In **Visual-studio-for-Mac 8.3.11** or **Visual Studio 16.4.2**:

After checking it in Xamarin Forms project, it actually can not work in `AppDelegate.cs`. And not finding the reason why not working , but it also works in Xamarin.iOS project .Finally , I found a **Workaround** in Xamarin.Forms project .

If is a Xamarin Forms Application , you can modify the color of the tab when it's selected by `SelectedTabColor`. As follow :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
            mc:Ignorable="d"
            SelectedTabColor="Black"
            xmlns:views="clr-namespace:AppTab2.Views"
            x:Class="AppTab2.Views.MainPage">

   '...

</TabbedPage>
```

Note: Tested version of Xamarin Forms is `4.4.0.991265` .

Comment: It does not work, the selected icon remains the default color

Comment: @Alessia What version of Xamarin Forms in your project ?